# Infinite loop when trying to count letter frequencies

Tags: c, loops, frequency, infinite, letter

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char string[100];
    int c = 0, count[26] = {0};
    int accum = 0;
    int a;

    while(1)
    {
       a = scanf("%s", string);
       while ( string[c] != '\0' )
       {

           if ( string[c] >= 'a' && string[c] <= 'z' ){
            count[string[c]-'a']++;
            accum++;
           }

           else if (string[c] >= 'A' && string[c] <= 'Z'){
            count[string[c]-'A']++;
            accum++;
           }
            c++;
       }
       if (a == EOF)
       {
           for ( c = 0 ; c < 26 ; c++ )
           {
            if( count[c] != 0 )
                printf( "%c %f\n", c+'a', ((double)count[c])/accum);
           }
       }
    }
   return 0;
}
```

So I have a program that counts the frequencies of letters that appear in standard input until EOF.  But once I reach EOF, my program just goes into an infinite loop and the frequencies doesn't seem to be right.  When I just put a print statement to enter a single string, it works fine.  I don't really know what the problem is.  Would anybody be able to help me with this?

Comment: You could declare "a" using scanf before the while loop and then check if a doesn't equal EOF before the loop's body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (a == EOF)` should be right after `a = scanf("%s", string);`

Then that `if()` condition should exist the loop.

Should reset `c = 0` each time in loop

```
while(1) {
   a = scanf("%s", string);
   if (a == EOF) {
     ...
     break;
   }
   c = 0;
   while ( string[c] != '\0' ) {
```

---

With the above changes, confident your code will run fine.  There are other things to consider on lesser degree.  1) The `scanf("%s",...` is unbounded.  2) Should limit input.  `if (a == EOF)` might as well code after the loop.  3) Suggest the loop condition is the positive affirmation that `scanf()==1`.  Loop on what is good, not exit on a case of what is bad.  4) Consider `unsigned` vs. `int` for counting.  5) A `for()` loop rather than `while()` is nice for incremental loops. 6) Avoid magic numbers like 26.

BTW: Your code had nice use of casting for floating point, `A` literals and array `{0}` initialization.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char string[100];
  unsigned count['z' - 'a' + 1] = { 0 };
  unsigned accum = 0;

  while (scanf("%99s", string) == 1) {
    for (int c = 0; string[c]; c++) {
      if (string[c] >= 'a' && string[c] <= 'z') {
        count[string[c] - 'a']++;
        accum++;
      } else if (string[c] >= 'A' && string[c] <= 'Z') {
        count[string[c] - 'A']++;
        accum++;
      }
    }
  }
  for (int c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
    if (count[c - 'a'] != 0)
      printf("%c %f\n", c, ((double) count[c - 'a']) / accum);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So what goes inside the if statement?

Comment: @user3880587 Simple append `break;` to the `if()` --> `if (a == EOF)
       {            for ( c = 0 ; c < 26 ; c++ )            {             if( count[c] != 0 )                 printf( "%c %f\n", c+'a', ((double)count[c])/accum);
           } break; }`

Answer (score 0):

The infinite loop is caused by this line:

```
while(1)
```

Remove it if you don't need it, or add a `break` statement somewhere.

Comment: Yeah I forgot about that.  But now, when I add the while loop, I tested it, and the input i put was "This is cool" and "What is this" it only gave me the letters for "This".

Answer (score 0):

Some more words to help describe your problem and the solution (as proposed by chux).

The first problem that you have is that you have no logic to exit the `while(1)` loop.

IE you have an infinite loop because that is what you have coded.

Even though you detect the EOF, you don't do anything about it: there is nothing in your code that says "Now that we have EOF, we need to exit this `while(1)` loop".

This is what chux is suggesting in his answer: that is what the `break` statement is for: it says "break out of the loop now".

You also have an additional problem that you are parsing the string before you check if you have EOF.  If `a` is `EOF`, then you must not parse the string, because you didn't get one.

So you need to rearrange your code so that your `EOF` check is before your string parsing, and when you finish printing the string after detecting `EOF`, you need to `break`.